# How to use Linq as an IF - Condition

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement

I got a little linq query searching for a customer in a database:

```
var query =
   from c in database.customer
   where c.ID == input
   select c;
```

Every customer has an ID, which in this case is set by an user-"input"

All customers in database are from "Germany" but some shall be copied into the database with a different value for country ("England" instead of "Germany")

Now, before adding them to the database directly, I want to check if there is already an "english version" of this customer in the database.

```
if (query.Where(c => c.country == "England"))
   //do nothing
else 
   //add the customer with c.country = "England"
```

The problem is that this is not a regular if-statement.

Is there a possible way to achieve what I want to express in this if-condition?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for `Any` instead of `Where`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just change condition to

```
if (query.Any(c => c.country.Equals("England")))
   //do nothing
else 
   //add the customer with c.country = "England"
```

`Linq` method `Where` returns `IEnumerable` value wchich can't be automatically converted into `bool` value.
Methods like `Any` or `All` returns `true` or `false` based on whether condition is `true` for at least one element in collection or all of them respectively.